# background-position can't be safed with web storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm working on a school project where i need to build a very simple website using html, css and java script. I'm not a professional coder, so please have mercy!

On my website i've got multiple "rooms", where you can click on various div-elements. If you do this, the java script counts the clicks and sets a variable (Status) up. Depending on the current status, another div-element gets moved by using the background-position. It's a png with three pictures inside. If you move to another "room" (new html page) it should be saved using web storage. The problem is, that every time you move on another page the png get's set to the background-position i defined in my style section. If i don't define a position, it get's positioned at 0px 0px, but not as it should do depending on the current status. But if i click the other div-element it get's moved like i want it in status==1. Only status==0 isn't working. Here is the relevant code:

```
<style>
        #AMPEL {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 255px;
        margin-left: 1425px;
        margin-top: 545px;
        background-image: url('ampel.png');
        background-position: 150px 0px;
        }       

        #ZAHLENBOX {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 220px;
        margin-left: 850px;
        width: 152px;
        height: 188px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
</style>
<body>
<div id='ZAHLENBOX'></div>
<div id='AMPEL'></div>
<script>
        var Status = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('KEY0'));
        function StatusDarstellen() {
            if (Status == 0) {                                                                  
                document.querySelector('#AMPEL').style.backgroundPosition = '150px 0px';        
            }
            if (Status == 1) {
                document.querySelector('#AMPEL').style.backgroundPosition = '300px 0px';
            }
            if (Status == 2) {
                document.querySelector('#AMPEL').style.backgroundPosition = '300px 0px';
            }
            if (Status == 3) {
                document.querySelector('#AMPEL').style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
            }

        document.querySelector('#ZAHLENBOX').addEventListener('click',Add1);
        
        var Status = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('KEY0'));        
        function Add1() {
            Status = Status + 1;
            StatusDarstellen();
            sessionStorage.setItem('KEY0',Status);
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when the window is loaded your div "learn" his background-position values from the css style section. At this point those values are not manipulated by the js script you made, because it is only fires on **click**.

you should fire the *StatusDarstellen* function just right after the page is loaded.
So add this code to the script just before the `</script>` :

```
window.onload = StatusDarstellen;
```

That should do it!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! You can't imagine how lucky you made a poor student from germany! Seriously, thanks a lot!!